# While importing the XML to MS Project, its Start and Finish date get changed

Tags: ms-project

**Description**

While importing the XML in MS Project then the start and finish dates get changed.

Please find the dates in XML

[Start and end date in XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxwnp.png)

Please find the MS output

[MS Project output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQWRb.png)

Get the XML file from here https://github.com/VigneshRameshh/GanttIssue

Help me to find the reason behind this?

Thanks in advance,
Vignesh Ramesh.

Comment: Please include the code to your post not use images on external sides.

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors that are affecting this.

1. The calendar that is applied to the project in the XML is the project's "Standard" calendar. This calendar only has 8 hour working days Monday-Friday, starting at 8:00 and ending at 17:00.

   [image: standard calendar]

   [image: calendar tags]
2. The amount of minutes of working time per day is set to 480, which is 8 hours

   [image]
3. The task is Auto Scheduled, not manually scheduled (the value would be 1 if it was manually scheduled).

   [image]

Given those parameters, MS Project cannot have the start of the task begin at 10/22/21 00:00 and finish on 10/23/21 00:00. Because the task is Auto scheduled, it must follow the Project's calendar and hours per day requirements. Therefore MS Project will start the task at the earliest point on 10/22/21 (8:00) and follow the 1 day duration applied to it, which will cause it to end on 10/22/21 17:00.

Note - it is ***not*** recommended to have tasks set to be Manually Scheduled. You want your tasks to be set to be Auto Scheduled.